# How can I make this 1st order ODE separable?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, substitution

$$ y (2+3xy) \,{\rm d} x = x (2-3xy) \,{\rm d} y $$

I tried using the substitution $y=\frac{v}{x}$, but that didn't get me far. Then I tried using the substitution $y=vx$, but that didn't work either. Any help, please?

Comment: I managed to do it using the substitution $y=\frac{v}{x}$ , perhaps more easily done if you start with it in the form $v=yx$. The result is a separable DE in $v$ and $x$.

Comment: How come? I first made $\frac{dy}{dx}$ the subject. Then I tried to plugin values for $y$ and $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and that's where I got stuck!

Comment: From $v=yx$ you get $\frac{dv}{dx} = x\frac{dy}{dx}+y$ hence $x^2\frac{dy}{dx}=x\frac{dv}{dx}-xy=x\frac{dv}{dx}-v$. Also from the DE $x^2\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2v+3v^2}{2-3v}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put, $xy=v$ then the equation reduces to $\dfrac{dv}{dx}=\dfrac{v}{x}.\dfrac{4}{2-3v}\implies 2\dfrac{dv}{v}-3v=4\dfrac{dx}{x}$

Integrating we get,

$v^2e^{-3v}=cx^4\implies y^2e^{-3xy}=cx^2$,which is the general solution.Here is the graph,

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\frac{dv}{dx}=\frac{v}{x} \cdot \frac{2+3v}{2-3v}+v?$

Comment: yes...............

Comment: I should've checked it properly before writing that :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can treat this as a theorem or a Rule:-

If the equation is $Mdx+Ndy=0$ and $Mx-Ny\neq 0$ . And the equation is of the form $yf(xy)dx+xF(xy)dy=0$.

Then $\frac{1}{Mx-Ny}$ is an integrating factor.

Here $Mx-Ny=4xy$.

So Multiplying by $\frac{1}{4xy}$. we have:-

$$\frac{1}{4x}(2+3xy)dx+\frac{1}{4y}(3xy-2)dy=0$$

$$\frac{1}{2x}dx+3ydx+3xdy-\frac{1}{2y}dy=0$$

$$=\frac{1}{2x}dx+3d(xy)-\frac{1}{2y}dy=0$$

Integrating you have:-

$$\frac{1}{2}\ln(\frac{x}{y})+3xy=C$$ as the solution

Answer (score 1):

Doing the same as @Kishalay Sarkar for
$$ x (2-3xy) \, y'-y (2+3xy)  =0$$
$$x y=v \implies  (3 v-2) v'+\frac{4 v}{x}=0\implies \frac 4x=\frac {(2-3v)v'}v$$
Integrating
$$4 \log(x)+c_1=2\log(v)-3 v$$ and the solution is given in terms of Lambert function
$$v=-\frac{2}{3} W\left(c_2\, x^2\right)\implies y=-\frac{2}{3x} W\left(c_2\, x^2\right)$$